# Newline delimited macro arguments

Tags: macros, plain-tex

Is it possible to define a macro, which takes newline delimited arguments?

```tex
\def\triple#1#2#3{(#1,#2,#3)}
```

Instead of this:

```tex
\triple
{First}
{Second}
{Third}
lorem ipsum
```

I would like to be able to write this:

```tex
\triple
First
Second
Third
lorem ipsum
```

Comment: by default a newline tokenizes as a space, you could use `\obeylines` but then like `\verb` your macro can not be used in the argument of any other macro

Comment: I think `\obeylines` should used in a group, which terminates the effect. I am looking for something, which terminates itself after three lines. Similar to arguments, which take as many as specified.

Comment: Yes I did that (`\obeylines` in a group) in the answer already posted

Answer (score 5):

As long as you are not nested in another macro you can use `\obeylines` so end of line is not tokenized as a space.

[image]

```
{\obeylines%
\gdef\triple{\bgroup\obeylines\xtriple}%
\gdef\xtriple^^M#1^^M#2^^M#3^^M{\egroup(#1,#2,#3) \ignorespaces}%
}%

Instead of this:

\triple
First
Second
Third
lorem ipsum


\bye
```

If you real examples, like this, don't have spaces in the items, a simpler definition would delimit the arguments on a space token and not need `\obeylines`.  This produces the same output as above

```
\def\triple #1 #2 #3 {(#1,#2,#3) }

Instead of this:

\triple
First
Second
Third
lorem ipsum


\bye
```

Comment: In the "simple" solution: could the arguments be in curly brackets and have spaces inside?

Comment: @Lupino yes sure braces would hide spaces or would hide newlines if you really needed that in the first version